# Android virtual button cover the view, how to make the view begin virtual bar right side

Tags: android, android-layout, view, virtual, hidden

I use fill_parent to set my view , but some android devices have virtual button on left of the screen which will hide my view. So is there any way that can set the view begin at right side of the virtual button.[image]

Or if I can set the virtual button invisiable?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `View::setSystemUiVisibility(flags)`, where the most important flags are `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE`.

Check out this link: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: @n-t any advice instead about how to exactly shrink the view in order to keep the virtual buttons visible ?